# Android UsbAccessory return null in android 8 and above

Tags: android, external-accessory, accessory

The below code works fine in android 7 and below version. But returns null on android 8 and above.

Does anyone know alternate solutions or permissions to make it work?

UsbAccessory[] accessories = mUsbManager.getAccessoryList();

Comment: did you make it work ?